How to override type class instance from package
In aeson.Types.ToJSON, there is already one call instances for ToJSON (Ratio Integer)
but it is show number like ("A" % "B") in JSON, I would like to make a custom version (sort of float-alike numbers) some where in my code:
instance ToJSON (Ratio Integer) where
  toJSON r = String $ pack $ show $ (numerator r) / (denominator r)

Then the GHC tells me it's overlapping, is there any way I can override the one from  Data.Aeson.Typtes.ToJSON for Ratio Integer ?
Thank you


You don't, typically you introduce a "signal interface".

Frame challenge: are you sure you must override toJSON? You can just write whatever function of type Rational -> Value you like and name it something else.

The whole point of using Ratio Integer over something like Double is that it can perfectly represent any rational number. Converting them into floating point to store in JSON means that you could be losing information. So overriding the ToJSON instance for Ratio Integer (even if you could do it) could cause problems, affecting any other usage that expected to be able to losslessly store rational numbers as JSON. Whereas calling a different function than toJSON (or using a different type than Ratio Integer) exactly where you need that behaviour is less invasive.

i.e. I would be looking at the place where you call toJSON @(Ratio Integer), rather than trying to change what toJSON @(Ratio Integer) does. (Which perhaps means using a non-default instance of ToJSON for your type that contains a Ratio Integer field)?

@Ben the idea is I  would like to use Ratio Integer for internal calculation, but in JSON response it's not human readable to show "234232 % 3241243" , so I would like to change it to float alike format .

@ShawnZhang: if you use a type parameter, you can convert it to a Float just before you serialize it.

You don't, typically you introduce a "signal interface", like:
newtype MyRatio = MyRatio (Ratio Integer)

instance ToJSON MyRatio where
  toJSON (MyRatio r) = String $ pack $ show $ (numerator r) / (denominator r)
and you thus wrap the values to serialize in the MyRatio data constructor.
